# plotting sine of a wiener process and calculating derivative

Tags: stochastic-calculus

How can I plot the sine of a Wiener process and compute its derivative? I only found the WienerProcess function in mathematica (version 9), but I'm not sure how to apply it.

Comment: FWIW, `data = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[.3, .5], {0, 1, 0.01}];
g[{a_, b_}] := {a, Sin[b]};
ds = Flatten[Normal[data], 1];
dg = Table[{i*.01, (ds[[i + 1, 2]] - ds[[i, 2]])/.01}, {i, 1, 100}];
ListLinePlot[g /@ ds]
ListLinePlot[dg]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
path = RandomFunction[WienerProcess[2, 3], {0, 10, 0.01}]["Path"];

sinofpath = {#1, Sin[#2]} & @@@ path;

derivativeofsin = 
   Transpose@{sinofpath[[All, 1]], DerivativeFilter[sinofpath[[All, 2]], {1}]};

derivativeofpath = 
   Transpose@{path[[All, 1]], DerivativeFilter[path[[All, 2]], {1}]};
```

I am not sure whether in your question you ask for the derivative of the sine of the path, or the derivative of the path itself. Both are calculated above anyway.

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[Legended[path, "original Wiener path"], 
   PlotStyle -> Darker@Purple, Filling -> Axis],

 ListLinePlot[Legended[sinofpath, "sin of path"]], 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: exactly what I wanted, thank you very much!